# sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 0 supplied

Tags: python, sqlite

I keep getting this error every time I try to use the delete button In my canteen manager application. The piece of code that causes the trouble:      .

```
c.execute("DELETE from addresses WHERE oid =  ?", reocordid.get()),
    reocordid.get(0, END)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `execute` method expects the substituted values to be a sequence of some kind.  For one item, you need to make it a tuple:

```
c.execute("DELETE from addresses WHERE oid = ?", (recordid.get(),))
```

I don't know what you're trying to do with the second half of that statement.

Comment: How do i do that

Comment: How do you do what?  I just gave you the statement you should be using.